# php-fpm "File not found" with nginx/vagrant and cent/os 7

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, vagrant

I have a vagrant box with centos 7

```
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
```

And I have php 7.1 and an nginx site configured on it (Symfony 3). The problem is when I access the site I get this error:

```
File not found.
```

Checking the nginx log I found this:

```
2017/02/25 15:04:19 [error] 15763#15763: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.56.1, server: site.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "site.dev"
```

Nginx is running as the www-data user:

```
www-data 15763  0.0  0.1  46292  3216 ?        S    13:16   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I though this could be related with a permissions problem, I check the file permissions of the vhost document root and I found that the owner is the user "games" wtf?

```
drwxr-xr-x.  8 501 games   272 feb 25 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 501 games   646 feb 25 12:08 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games  1189 feb 25 10:28 app_dev.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games  2092 feb 25 10:28 apple-touch-icon.png
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games   631 feb 25 10:28 app.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games 21486 feb 25 10:28 config.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games  6518 feb 25 10:28 favicon.ico
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 501 games   116 feb 25 10:28 robots.txt
```

But if I try to do a chown I get a operation not permitted error.

Here's the vhost config file:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name {{www_domain}};
   return 301 https://{{www_domain}}$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name {{www_domain}};
    root   {{www_document_root}};

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.key;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{www_domain}}.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/{{www_domain}}.error.log error;

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    ## Static files are served directly.
    location \/images\/(.*)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
        ## fell swoop.
        tcp_nodelay off;
        ## Set the OS file cache.
        open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 45s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
    }

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

Comment: is `www-data` user running php too, can you run `ps aux | grep 'php-fpm'`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes. And I try to changed to "games" and the problem persists. I have no idea how to debug why php-fpm is giving me this File not found error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was strugling with this exact problem for a couple hours and couldn't find a solution *until* I switched to a different vagrant box and it magically started working.

I'm now using `config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.3"` instead of `centos/7`.

I don't know what the differences are between the boxes. If anyone could tell me why one works and the other doesn't, then I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `SELINUX`, for my running this command solve the problem

```
$ setenforce 0
$ sed -i 's/SELINUX=\(enforcing\|permissive\)/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config
```